# How to prepend common scripts to all specific ones using Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

In my project, I'm using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix) to compile the assets.

I have **2 common scripts** - jQuery and navigation - and **multiple site-specific ones**, like home.js, about.js, etc.

I want to prepend the common scripts to each of the site-specific ones, so, for example, the final home_scripts.js file would include:

1. jquery.min.js
2. navigation.js
3. home.js

The idea is to serve a single, non-bloated JS file per page.

How would I go about it?

Note: I know I could just use `mix.js(...)` function for each site and simply copy-paste the paths to the 2 common scripts at the beginning, but I'm hoping for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CommonJS to achieve something like this.

In `home.js`

```
require('jquery');
require('./navigation');

// Home page specific logic here
```